# MDT EventRegister nuget exited with code 1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

While building my project, Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.exe exited with code 1 and failing the build. 
The issue is first of it's kind so any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
Severity Code Description Project Path File Line Suppression State
Error The command ""C:\Users\uanand\Desktop\UPDATE\courier_ua\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28\build\eventRegister.exe" -DumpRegDlls @"C:\Users\uanand\Desktop\UPDATE\courier_ua\Apttus.Workers.NotificationProxyWorker\bin\x64\Debug\Apttus.Workers.NotificationProxyWorker.eventRegister.rsp" "C:\Users\uanand\Desktop\UPDATE\courier_ua\Apttus.Workers.NotificationProxyWorker\bin\x64\Debug\Apttus.Workers.NotificationProxyWorker.dll" " exited with code 1.    Apttus.Workers.NotificationProxyWorker
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Did you work it out on your side?

Comment: @PierrOz Yes, the solution provided below worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed these packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource" version="1.1.28" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister" version="1.1.28" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I only use

```
<package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.Redist" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Then, in the projects .csproj file, I removed these elements:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28\build\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28\build\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.targets'))" />
```

and

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28\build\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28\build\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.targets')" />
```